# Sorting pandas datafame as per given sort order list

Tags: pandas

I have prepared a code for pivot table, I could not be able to sort the columns of dataframe on my own way. Could you please let me know what shall i code for sorting columns as per given sort_order list.

My Code

```
d = {'ID': [1,2,1,2,3], 'Month':["Apr-20","May-20","Jun-20","Apr-20","Aug-20"],'Value1':[10,10,10,10,10],
                                                                                 'Value2':[20,20,20,20,20],
                                                                                 'Value3':[30,30,30,30,30],
                                                                                 'Value4':[40,40,40,40,40]}
dfa = pd.DataFrame(d)
dfa = dfa.loc[(pd.to_datetime(dfa.Month, format='%b-%y')).dt.month.sort_values().index]

df_pvt =    pd.pivot_table(dfa, values=['Value1','Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'],
                        index=['ID'],
                        columns=['Month'],
                        aggfunc=np.sum,
                        fill_value=0)    
df_pvt
```

Given sort order list:

```
sort_order = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

Output of Pivot table, Which could not be able sort month columns as per given order.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If possible convert `Month` column to datetimes, then use `pivoting` with sorting by default and then using rename in last step use:

```
dfa['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa['Month'], format='%b-%y')

df_pvt =    pd.pivot_table(dfa, values=['Value1','Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'],
                        index=['ID'],
                        columns=['Month'],
                        aggfunc=np.sum,
                        fill_value=0)    

df_pvt = df_pvt.rename(columns = lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'), level=1)
print (df_pvt)
      Value1                      Value2                      Value3         \
Month Apr-20 May-20 Jun-20 Aug-20 Apr-20 May-20 Jun-20 Aug-20 Apr-20 May-20   
ID                                                                            
1         10      0     10      0     20      0     20      0     30      0   
2         10     10      0      0     20     20      0      0     30     30   
3          0      0      0     10      0      0      0     20      0      0   

                    Value4                       
Month Jun-20 Aug-20 Apr-20 May-20 Jun-20 Aug-20  
ID                                               
1         30      0     40      0     40      0  
2          0      0     40     40      0      0  
3          0     30      0      0      0     40
```

Another idea with ordered categoricals - first sort values by [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and datetimes and then convert values by [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
dfa = dfa.iloc[pd.to_datetime(dfa['Month'], format='%b-%y').argsort()]
dfa['Month'] = pd.Categorical(dfa['Month'], ordered=True, categories=dfa['Month'].unique())

df_pvt =    pd.pivot_table(dfa, values=['Value1','Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'],
                        index=['ID'],
                        columns=['Month'],
                        aggfunc=np.sum,
                        fill_value=0)    

print (df_pvt)
      Value1                      Value2                      Value3         \
Month Apr-20 May-20 Jun-20 Aug-20 Apr-20 May-20 Jun-20 Aug-20 Apr-20 May-20   
ID                                                                            
1         10      0     10      0     20      0     20      0     30      0   
2         10     10      0      0     20     20      0      0     30     30   
3          0      0      0     10      0      0      0     20      0      0   

                    Value4                       
Month Jun-20 Aug-20 Apr-20 May-20 Jun-20 Aug-20  
ID                                               
1         30      0     40      0     40      0  
2          0      0     40     40      0      0  
3          0     30      0      0      0     40
```

EDIT: If need new levels aded to `MultiIndex DataFrame` is necessary create `MultiIndex in df` first:

```
df_pvt = df_pvt.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1) 
df_pvt = df_pvt.sort_index(axis=1, level='Month')
df = df_pvt.sum(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['sum'],df.columns])
```

And here because `CategoricalIndex` is also necessary add new category by [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) and [`CategoricalIndex.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.add_categories.html):

```
added = df_pvt.columns.levels[0].add_categories(['sum'])

df_pvt.columns = df_pvt.columns.set_levels(added, level=0)

#verify levels
print (df_pvt.columns.levels)
[['Apr-20', 'May-20', 'Jun-20', 'Aug-20'], ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4']]
print (df.columns.levels)
[['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'], ['sum']]

df_pvt = df_pvt.join(df) 
print (df_pvt)
Month Apr-20                      May-20                      Jun-20         \
      Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value1 Value2   
ID                                                                            
1         10     20     30     40      0      0      0      0     10     20   
2         10     20     30     40     10     20     30     40      0      0   
3          0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0   

Month               Aug-20                         sum                       
      Value3 Value4 Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4  
ID                                                                           
1         30     40      0      0      0      0     20     40     60     80  
2          0      0      0      0      0      0     20     40     60     80  
3          0      0     10     20     30     40     10     20     30     40
```

Comment: Used Categorial Method and added couple line as below.
df_pvt = df_pvt.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
df_pvt = df_pvt.sort_index(axis=1, level='Month')
df = df_pvt.sum(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Total'], df.columns])
df_pvt = df_pvt.join(df)

But throws below error TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex 

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this to sort and keep the formatting of the Month column in the original dataframe.

```py
dfa.loc[(pd.to_datetime(dfa.Month, format='%b-%y')).dt.month.sort_values().index]
```

[image]

### Handling the Pivot Table

```py
# preprocess the field: Month
#    1. read-in as datetime field
#    2. Sort the dataframe with the Month columns
#    3. format the datetime field to 
#       keep theoriginal appearance: MMM-YY
#    >> NOTE: the previous step (#3) makes it convert  
#       into str from datetime
dfb = dfa.copy()
dfb['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa.Month, format='%b-%y')
dfb = dfb.loc[dfb.Month.dt.month.sort_values().index]

## Pivot Table (based on datetime values in Month column)
##       and rename the column names of the months (at level=1)
##       with datetime-string-format: '%b-%Y' for MMM-YY
dfp = (pd.pivot_table(dfb, values = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'], 
               index = ['ID'], columns = ['Month'], 
               aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
        .rename(columns = lambda months: months.strftime('%b-%y'), level=1))
```

[image]

### Dummy Data

The dummy data shared by the OP has a typo: `June` instead of `Jun`. This version is corrected and does not need one to fix it.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID': [1,2,1,2,3], 
     'Month':["Apr-20","May-20","Jun-20","Apr-20","Aug-20"],
     'Value1':[10,10,10,10,10], 
     'Value2':[20,20,20,20,20], 
     'Value3':[30,30,30,30,30], 
     'Value4':[40,40,40,40,40]
     }
dfa = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

EDIT: In my opinion, this solution of sorting with datetime values and then converting them to string-formatted values (`MMM-YY`) is the most straight forward and convenient method to achieve the given requirement. Also, this implementation is practically very close/identical-*ish* to what @jezrael shared. This is why I have already voted-up @jezrael's solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am expecting it to closely follow the given sort_order list.

Comment: When i generate pivot table, the columns does not sort out in proper way

Comment: I will post an update to specifically follow the given sort order.

Comment: Edited my question with your suggestion and attached output of the code which is not getting as per requirement. Please help me to get it in right order,